# How Do I Get The Full Path Of A Selected Directory And Then Use That Directory Within The Code

Tags: vb.net, directory, file-extension, folderbrowserdialog, directoryinfo

I have currently created code which grabs a ceratin file extension and puts it into a certain folder.

```
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(
"C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Excel Files")

        Dim filePaths31 = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.xlsx")

        For Each filePath31 In filePaths31
            Dim filename31 = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath31)
            Dim newPath31 = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Excel Files", filename31)

            If IO.File.Exists(newPath31) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Please check if the file elready exists")

                Return

            End If

            IO.File.Move(filePath31, newPath31)

        Next filePath31

        MessageBox.Show("Excel Files Compiled And Cleaned")
```

This code works well although the directory implemented inside the code and should be different for every user.

I have experimented with this code here which allows a user to select a directory, although now I need help assigning that full directory into `IO.Path.Combine(users chosen directory here + \Excel Files, filename31`

```
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim grade As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
```

This code I believe grabs the user directory and stores it in the grade variable. I need to figure out how to store that 'grade' variable into my code, and also create a new folder in that directory that is specified in the code.

Comment: Your question amounts to how to store a `String` in a variable for later use and how to create a subfolder path. Those are not things you need to ask about on SO.

Comment: Right, but is it possible to convert my variable into a string? Or do I need another method?

Comment: If you want a `String` variable then declare a `String` variable rather than a `DirectoryInfo` variable. That `SelectedPath` property is already a `String`. If you think that you need a `DirectoryInfo` object then you would need to get the path as a `String` from that. Have you researched the `DirectoryInfo` class to see how you might do that? SO is not a place that you come to be taught the basics so you need to do your own research first. If you're using a `DirectoryInfo` and haven't read the documentation for that class then you haven't done your research.